# GraphQL relations leaking data, even with context.user resolver already set. How to prevent data exposure via relations?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, graphene-python

How is everyone doing authentication across relations to prevent data from being traversed via relations?

For example we have a Shop which has Users.

```
// Returns error as i've set custom resolver to allow only context.user.is_shop_owner
{
  shops {
    name
    users {
      email
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

This query is normally blocked with a custom resolver like `context.user.is_shop_owner`, so you cannot execute this from root query.

However, if a malicious person traverses relations to reach the users object he is able to get the sensitive user data.

```
// Data exposed un-intendedly due to relation traversal. How to prevent this?
{
  products {
    name
    price
    shop {
      users { ... } // boom, exposed
    }
  }
}
```

Is this a flaw in graphql? **How are you guys working around this**?

This is on a python-graphene stack btw.

Edit: Btw, i know we can do `exclude_fields`, but then i won't be able to access Users from the ShopNode, which is an important information to query for the ShopNode, so limiting fields are probably not a good idea. (edited)

Comment: are you using Django for this, can you show your view when you return your users?

Comment: @MauricioCortazar I don't use Django views, sorry!

Comment: Schema* i mean *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wound up setting custom resolvers for each node to block out the relations you want to limit access to based on the `context.user`. Refer to the code below in response to my question above.

```
class ProductNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node)
        # Exclude nodes where you do not need any access at all
        exclude_fields = ['users']

    # For nodes where you need specific/limited access, define custom resolvers.
    # This prevents the relation traversal loophole
    def resolve_shop(self, args, context, info):
        """ Allow access to nodes only for staff or shop owner and manager """
        if get_is_staff_user(context.user, self):
            return self.shop

        Operations.raise_forbidden_access_error()
```

Answer (score 2):

This should probably be controlled within the `Shop` type, to return `null` when the user does not have the right permissions. Otherwise if a `Shop` were accessed from a second field, you'd have to duplicate the check.

Comment: How would you implement that ?